# Using image magick with php to resize an image while fetching from the database

Tags: php, mysql, image-processing, imagemagick

In php I have uploaded an image to the database by using php move_uploaded_file function. Now when I am getting the image from the database I am using this code to get the image

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM "._DB_PREFIX_."storeimages WHERE `city_name`='".$_GET['details']."'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo '<div class="store-img">';
  echo '<img class="store-image" src="storeimages/images/'.$row['store_image'].'" width="100px" height="100px" >';
  echo '</div>';
  }
```

Here I am getting the image easily. But here you can see I have used `width="100px"` and `height="100px"` for image size. This is disturbing the image aspect ratio. To solve this I have searched over google and I got that [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is a good option for that.But I don't know how to use imagemagick with simple php (I am not using any class, method) and how can I use imagemagick here? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: PHP GD is simpler than using imagemagick, and most hosting already support it.

Comment: defining equal height and width would of course produce a square so if your original image is not square then it will not have its aspect preserved. I would advise only using the height attribute and deleting the width attribute - see if this gives you the result you are seeking (vertical uniformity)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to maintain image ratio

```
list($origWidth, $origHeight) = @getimagesize("path/to/image");

$origRatio = $origWidth/$origHeight;
$resultWidth = 100;
$resultHeight = 100;
if ( $resultWidth/$resultHeight > $origRatio ) {
    $resultWidth = $resultHeight * $origRatio;
} else {
    $resultHeight = $resultWidth / $origRatio;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Sencha .io . Is very easy and powerful

```
echo '<img
  src="http://src.sencha.io/100/http://yourdomain.com/storeimages/images/'.$row['store_image'].'"
  alt="My constrained image"
  width="100"
  height="100"
/>';
```

More information there: http://www.sencha.com/learn/how-to-use-src-sencha-io/

Answer (score 0):

imagemagick is a linux utility through which you can manipulate images

In order to use , you must have it installed on your server

just type following command

```
<?
 print_r(exec("which convert"));
?>
```

if it return something then it is installed

Now use following command to resize image

```
<?php

exec("/<linux path of this utility>/convert  /<actual path of image>/a.png  -resize 200x200  /<path where image to be saved>/a200x200.png")


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. its not a good practice to use HTML within PHP, remove HTML from PHP
2. install php imagick

   ```
   sudo apt-get install imagemagick
   sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
   ```
3. While resizing the photo is better to maintain the aspect ratio
   of the photo. Following code should give a better idea of how to 
   calculate the aspect ratio

   ```
   if( $imageWidth > $maxWidth OR $imageHeight > $maxHeight )
   {
      $widthRatio = 0;
      $heightRatio = 0;

      if( $imageWidth > 0 )
      {
          $widthRatio = $maxWidth/$imageWidth;
      }

      if( $imageHeight > 0 )
      {
          $heightRatio = $maxHeight/$imageHeight;
      }

      if( $widthRatio > $heightRatio )
      {
          $resizeRatio = $heightRatio;
      }
      else
      {
          $resizeRatio = $widthRatio;
      }

      $newWidth = intval( $imageWidth * $resizeRatio );

      $newHeight = intval( $imageHeight * $resizeRatio );

    }
   ```
4. Refer http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php for how to use Imagick. You can refer the following sample code

   ```
    $image = new Imagick($pathToImage);
    $image->thumbnailImage($newWidth, $newHeight);
    $image->writeImage($pathToNewImage);
   ```